# No such method for createFromSecret()

Tags: azure-ad-msal, azure-keyvault, azure-data-explorer, kusto-java-sdk

I am using msal4j library on version 0.6.0-preview and java 8 in the repo.

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>msal4j</artifactId>
                <version>0.6.0-preview</version>
            </dependency>
```

This msal4j library is to set up Azure keyvault as well as kusto data ingestion.

Here's my code:

```
ConnectionStringBuilder csb = ConnectionStringBuilder.createWithAadApplicationCredentials(clusterPath, appId, appKey, authorityId);
Client kustoClient = ClientFactory.createClient(csb);
```

`createClient()` failed because in `TokenProviderFactory.java`, it is expecting `createFromSecret()` but `ClientCredentialFactory.java` does not have `createFromSecret()` but `create()`. Thus it is throwing me an error:

```
 com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(Ljava/lang/String;)
    Lcom/microsoft/aad/msal4j/IClientSecret;
| java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(Ljava/lang/String;)
    Lcom/microsoft/aad/msal4j/IClientSecret;
                    at com.microsoft.azure.kusto.data.auth.TokenProviderFactory.createTokenProvider(TokenProviderFactory.java:25)
                    at com.microsoft.azure.kusto.data.ClientImpl.<init>(ClientImpl.java:52)
                    at com.microsoft.azure.kusto.data.ClientFactory.createClient(ClientFactory.java:16)
```

Here's the limitations we face:

1. We are not able to upgrade java 11 in our repo due to other dependencies so we are stuck with java 8.
2. We are not able to upgrade the msal4j library to higher version due to other dependencies.

But regardless of that, why is the `TokenProviderFactory.java` has the following code;

```
clientSecret clientSecret = ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(csb.getApplicationKey());
```

But `ClientCredentialFactory.java` does not have `createFromSecret()`? What can we do as a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this issue would be to do the authentication yourselves and create the client with a token provider

```
 ConnectionStringBuilder.createWithAadTokenProviderAuthentication(null, () -> getToken())
```

The best solution would be to use versions that suite most dependencies. Use
maven helper intellij plugin to find this out.

Other options to avoid any collision is to shadow the Kusto library and its dependencies.

As for the question - the reason why createFromSecret doesnt seem to be in ClientCredentialFactory is that the method does not exist on your version but does exist in the version Kusto SDK is using.

Comment: Thanks! I think that's the right direction. Do you know if Azure provides any example for generating access token? I can't find anything online..

Comment: Azure samples repo is a good place for SDKs
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-msal-java-samples
You can follow the logic on the Kusto Java repo as well
https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-java/